# How to define an xmmword variable in IDA?

Tags: ida

How to define an xmmword variable in IDA?
[image]

IDA identified one variable as xmmword but I can't find a menu to define other variables around it as xmmwords:
[image]

I also tried to set the type after pressing `Y` key, and set it as `xmmword`, and also tried to set the strtuct type after pressing `Alt+Q` keys, but there is no `xmmword` in neither of those 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was `Options -> Setup data types...` and then choosing `octa word`:
[image]

Comment: You can mark your answer as approved.

Comment: @sudhackar no, I can't, not yet.